HTTP Request Working in Postman But Not In My Swift App
I have a vapor server running and I am attempting to use bearer token authentication. I am able to login and get a token back in response. In Postman I can use the token value to authenticate my route and receive the correct response back (an array of Resident). In my app I'm using the new token value with authentication set to Bearer but I get a 401 response. What is Postman putting in its HTTP request that I'm missing in my app?
Here's my app HTTP request function:
func getResidents() async throws -> [Resident] {
       
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(API.url)/residents")!)
        
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(token?.value)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            
            // Make the request
        let (data, response) = try await session.data(for: request)
            
        print(response)
            // Ensure we had a good response (status 200)
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                throw GetResidentsError.unableToGetResidents
            }
        print(httpResponse.statusCode)
            
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let residents = try decoder.decode([Resident].self, from: data)
        
        print(residents)
        return residents
    }

Here's my Postman get request with bearer authentication:


Could you print request.allHTTPHeaderFields? Because "Bearer \(token?.value)" seems wrong to me, see what's the output of that you might understand your issue.

Note: due to ATS You cannot use scheme http in iOS - unless you explicitly allow it. You can read more about it here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/6767 and here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/.
Also note, that you should not use a Bearer token over an unsecured connection.

Additionally, you should not set a Content-Type header in your GET request - instead you may use an Accept header.

Larme's response led me to the answer. The printout as requested was:
Optional(["Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer Optional("2Qo8hWuzbmNu2EImpeXDYQ==")"])
I was not unwrapping the optional before putting the token value in the header. After unwrapping it my request was successful.
Thanks!
Here's the re-factored code:
func getResidents() async throws -> [Resident] {
        
        guard let token = self.token else { return [Resident(id: UUID(), firstName: "", middleName: "", lastName: "", phoneNumber: "", email: "", dob: "", address: "", rentAmount: 0, pastDueRentOwed: 0, isPastDue: false, isRetiredClient: false, monthlyReminderScheduled: false, house: "", roomNumber: 0, bedNumber: 0, housePin: 0, moveInDate: Date().formatted(date: .numeric, time: .omitted))] }
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(API.url)/residents")!)
        
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(token.value)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
//        print(request.allHTTPHeaderFields)
            // Make the request
        let (data, response) = try await session.data(for: request)
            
        print(response)
            // Ensure we had a good response (status 200)
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                throw GetResidentsError.unableToGetResidents
            }
        print(httpResponse.statusCode)
            
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let residents = try decoder.decode([Resident].self, from: data)
        
        return residents
    }


For completeness you should post the code that solved the problem and not just the reason for it

Thanks for the suggestion, I made the edit.
